# Google Timezone API key

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm trying to implement Google's [Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro) and even though I have generated a Browser API key, added it to my code, and added the referrer to the Google Developers Console, I am still getting the following error when trying to use JavaScript to return the data:

> This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API
>   key. Request received from IP address 12.34.56.789, with referer:
>   https://www.example.com/timezone

My referrer in the developers console is

> *.example.com/*

The documentation says I need a server key but I tried and it didn't work either (and it doesn't make sense to need a server key vs a browse key).

And ideas of what I can check to see why this isn't working?  If I delete the referrer, everything works.  So, I know it has something to do with that but the referrer matches the wildcard according to Google's own documentation.  Furthermore, even if I enter the referrer exactly as the error indicates, I still get the REQUEST_DENIED status.

Answer (score 2):

Figuring this was a bug in the API, I logged an issue with Google support.  Turns out, there currently does not exist a JavaScript API for time zone, only a Web Service that requires a Server Key.  Here's the link to the issue on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9179).

Still needing a way to get timezone info from lat/lng I started using [timezonedb.com](http://timezonedb.com/).  There is no way to limit referrer but at least it's something.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer, but should "There is now way..." be  "There is _no_ way..."? It's a minor edit you might want to make to improve your post.

Comment: That's what I get for being in a hurry. Thanks!